# Pubspec dependencies only for one platform

Tags: flutter

I need to use the firebase messaging dependency only for the android platform.

```
dependencies:
  firebase_messaging: 4.0.0+1
```

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If you add such a dependency, you get what it contains.

You could fork the plugin and remove the iOS specific stuff and use the fork as dependency (git dependeny, path dependency, or normal dependency if you plublish the for to pub.dartlang.org)