# Extracting packages for Android in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, android-package-managers, flutter-packages

I am using the advertising_id package in my flutter project. This package helps me generate a unique ID on the Android side, but it prompts me to ask for a different permission on the iOS side. Can I add this package only for Android without affecting the iOS side?

I did not try to separate it for android in the pubspeck.yaml file, I did not try to separate it in the gradle part.

Comment: Well, you can just add the package to your pubspec but only initialize/use the package if you are on Android. You can check the platform using the `Platform` class from the `dart:io` library.

Comment: It already checks the platform, but on the iOS side, it asks us to add permissions during build and we do not want the user to show this permission. Also, it does not ask for permission on the Android side, it only asks for permission on the iOS side.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127479/pubspec-dependencies-only-for-one-platform It seems like it isn't possible to add a dependency only for one platform. If the package wants you to add the permissions for iOS you must create a fork of the github repo as explained in the link above and remove all the iOS code.